# Set foreground color of button

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I generated a Button dynamically, now I need to change the foreground color and set a BorderBrush.
But I can't use code like `btn.Foreground = Brushes.Yellow;`

VS2013 is warning that 'Brushes does not exist.'

Comment: use SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Include this assembly **'System.Windows.Media'**

```
btn.Foreground=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
```

Comment: Ths ,first have to using Windows.UI;

Comment: See the edit You need to include the assembly 'using System.Windows.Media'